# Is tooling available to 'assemble' WebAssembly to x86-64 native code?

Tags: compilation, x86-64, executable, machine-code, webassembly

I am guessing that a Wasm binary is usually JIT-compiled to native code, but given a Wasm source, is there a tool to see the actual generated x86-64 machine code?
Or asked in a different way, is there a tool that consumes Wasm and outputs  native code?

Comment: What about something like WebAssembly Explorer? Example: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/get-started-with-webassembly-using-only-14-lines-of-javascript-b37b6aaca1e4

Comment: WebAssembly can be [compiled to C](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt/tree/main/wasm2c), so it can be compiled to any architecture that a C compiler supports.

Answer (score 4):

The online [WasmExplorer](https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/) compiles C code to both WebAssembly and FireFox x86, using the SpiderMonkey compiler. Given the following simple function:

```
int testFunction(int* input, int length) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    sum += input[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Here is the x86 output:

```
wasm-function[0]:
  sub rsp, 8                            ; 0x000000 48 83 ec 08
  cmp esi, 1                            ; 0x000004 83 fe 01
  jge 0x14                              ; 0x000007 0f 8d 07 00 00 00
 0x00000d:                              
  xor eax, eax                          ; 0x00000d 33 c0
  jmp 0x26                              ; 0x00000f e9 12 00 00 00
 0x000014:                              
  xor eax, eax                          ; 0x000014 33 c0
 0x000016:                              ; 0x000016 from: [0x000024]
  mov ecx, dword ptr [r15 + rdi]        ; 0x000016 41 8b 0c 3f
  add eax, ecx                          ; 0x00001a 03 c1
  add edi, 4                            ; 0x00001c 83 c7 04
  add esi, -1                           ; 0x00001f 83 c6 ff
  test esi, esi                         ; 0x000022 85 f6
  jne 0x16                              ; 0x000024 75 f0
 0x000026:                              
  nop                                   ; 0x000026 66 90
  add rsp, 8                            ; 0x000028 48 83 c4 08
  ret
```

You can [view this example online](https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/?state=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22showGutter%22%3Atrue%2C%22showConsole%22%3Atrue%2C%22showOptions%22%3Atrue%2C%22autoCompile%22%3Atrue%2C%22showLLVM%22%3Afalse%2C%22darkMode%22%3Atrue%2C%22fastMath%22%3Afalse%2C%22noInline%22%3Afalse%2C%22noRTTI%22%3Afalse%2C%22noExceptions%22%3Afalse%2C%22cleanWast%22%3Afalse%2C%22wasmBaseline%22%3Afalse%2C%22dialect%22%3A%22C%2B%2B11%22%2C%22optimizationLevel%22%3A%22s%22%7D%2C%22source%22%3A%22int%20testFunction(int*%20input%2C%20int%20length)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20int%20sum%20%3D%200%3B%5Cn%20%20for%20(int%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20length%3B%20%2B%2Bi)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20sum%20%2B%3D%20input%5Bi%5D%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20return%20sum%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

WasmExplorer compiles code into wasm / x86 via a service - you can see the [scripts that are run on Github](https://github.com/wasdk/wasmexplorer-service/tree/master/scripts) - you should be able to use these to construct a command-line tool yourself.

Comment: Correction: Chrome didn't update its compiler, it *added* an additional compiler. Whether V8's source code is the easiest to follow is another question.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasRossberg good point - although I updated the answer, I just remembered that WasmExplorer outputs x86 assembly

Comment: That's pretty inefficient!  Aren't there any better ahead-of-time compilers to produce WASM?  It can't even get the loop down to 4 or fewer uops so it can run at 1 per clock on Haswell / Skylake?  This is 5.  Using `add eax, [r15+rdi]` would save a uop (except on Sandybridge), and `test esi,esi` is also useless after `add esi, -1` already set flags according to the result.

Comment: Not to mention that this could auto-vectorize easily, and run 4x faster with SSE2 `paddd xmm0, [r15+rdi]` for arrays that aren't tiny, with just a bit of extra code for loop startup / end.

Comment: `WasmExplorer compiles C code to both WebAssembly and FireFox x86` Really? The x86 assembly is compiled straight from the C and not from the wasm? That's disappointing. Or is it just the wording isn't clear?

Comment: Are you sure? I've been looking through the code and I can't find anything invoking spidermonkey or firefox. In the .sh files in your link I can only find code that invokes LLVM for C->wasm and LLVM for C->x86. I can't seem to find the code in the repo that does wasm->x86.