# Compile webassembly to native executable

Tags: webassembly, transpiler

Are there any tools (yet) which can compile a wasm module to a native executable (eg. an ELF or .exe file)? Something like emscripten but in reverse. Failing that, is there any other way to run webassembly outside of a browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is tooling available to 'assemble' WebAssembly to x86-64 native code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111076/is-tooling-available-to-assemble-webassembly-to-x86-64-native-code)

Comment: That's mostly the same question. Though I really want a tool that can output an executable, not just show me the machine code on a website.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a wabt tool called wasm2c which can convert your wasm module to C.  This can then be compiled to native code:
https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt/tree/master/wasm2c